ActiveMQ Artemis message multicast divert anycast failed
I'm trying to divert a multicast address to anycast address and bridge the anycast data to other servers. Fortunately, there is also such an example in divert.
After everything is ready, I set the JmsTemplate PubSubDomain to true and send a message to multicast. The Queue under multicast can receive the message normally, but divert does not seem to work because the bridge server will not receive the message.
If I change the way, that is, use artemisClient to send messages, everything works fine, multicast. The queue and bridge server will receive the message. The only bad thing is that the web-console cannot preview the message text message, and will get the prompt "Unsupported message body type which cannot be displayed by hawtio." Is there a better solution?
<core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core">

    <name>subscribe-embedded-artemis</name>

    <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

    <journal-type>MAPPED</journal-type>

    <paging-directory>prinect-data-flow/activemq-artemis/data/paging</paging-directory>

    <bindings-directory>prinect-data-flow/activemq-artemis/data/bindings</bindings-directory>

    <journal-directory>prinect-data-flow/activemq-artemis/data/journal</journal-directory>

    <large-messages-directory>prinect-data-flow/activemq-artemis/data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

    <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

    <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

    <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

    <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

    <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

    <journal-buffer-timeout>40000</journal-buffer-timeout>

    <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>

    <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
    <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

    <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
         that won't support flow control. -->
    <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

    <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
    <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

    <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

    <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

    <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>


    <page-sync-timeout>1352000</page-sync-timeout>

    <connectors>
        <connector name="remote-connector">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
    </connectors>

    <acceptors>
        <acceptor name="netty">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?protocols=AMQP,CORE</acceptor>
    </acceptors>

    <diverts>
        <divert name="multicastToAnycastDivert">
            <routing-name>toAnycast</routing-name>
            <address>dataSubTopic</address>
            <forwarding-address>forwardMessageToCloud</forwarding-address>
            <exclusive>false</exclusive>
        </divert>
    </diverts>

    <bridges>
        <bridge name="my-bridge">
            <queue-name>forwardMessageToCloud</queue-name>
            <forwarding-address>remotePrinectDataForward</forwarding-address>
            <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
            <static-connectors>
                <connector-ref>remote-connector</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
        </bridge>
    </bridges>

    <security-settings>
        <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="guest"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="guest"/>
        </security-setting>
    </security-settings>

    <address-settings>
        <address-setting match="#">
            <!-- default is 1.0 -->
            <redelivery-delay-multiplier>1.5</redelivery-delay-multiplier>
            <!-- default is 0 (no delay) -->
            <redelivery-delay>5000</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- default is 0.0) -->
            <redelivery-collision-avoidance-factor>0.15</redelivery-collision-avoidance-factor>
            <!-- default is redelivery-delay * 10 -->
            <max-redelivery-delay>50000</max-redelivery-delay>
            <dead-letter-address>DLA</dead-letter-address>
            <max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>
            <auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
            <dead-letter-queue-prefix/>
            <dead-letter-queue-suffix>.DLQ</dead-letter-queue-suffix>

            <expiry-address>expiryAddress</expiry-address>
            <auto-create-expiry-resources>true</auto-create-expiry-resources>
            <expiry-queue-prefix/>
            <expiry-queue-suffix>.EXP</expiry-queue-suffix>
        </address-setting>
    </address-settings>

    <addresses>
        <address name="DLA">
            <anycast>
                <queue name="DLA"/>
            </anycast>
        </address>
        <address name="dataSubTopic">
            <multicast>
                <queue name="dataSubQueue1"/>
                <queue name="dataSubQueue2"/>
            </multicast>
        </address>
        <address name="forwardMessageToCloud">
            <anycast>
                <queue name="forwardMessageToCloud"/>
            </anycast>
        </address>
    </addresses>
</core>

public void jmsSend(String message) {
    jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("dataSubTopic", message);
}

public void clientSend(String message) {
    try (ClientSession session = artemisServerLocatorConfig.serverLocator()
            .createSessionFactory()
            .createSession()) {

        session.start();
        ClientProducer producer = session.createProducer("dataSubTopic");
        ClientMessage clientMessage = session.createMessage(true);
        clientMessage.setType(Message.TEXT_TYPE);
        clientMessage.getBodyBuffer()
                .writeString(message);
        producer.send(clientMessage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("message = {}", e.getMessage());
    }
}



Can you provide the relevant configuration from broker.xml (i.e. divert(s), address(es), queue(s), etc.)?

Sorry, I didn't upload broker.xml because I used programmatic configuration, I have added the file in the question

I did a quick proof-of-concept with 2 instances of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.38.0 as well as 2 instances of 2.19.1. On the first broker instance I added the following to broker.xml based on your config:
      ...
      <connectors>
         <connector name="remote-connector">tcp://localhost:61617</connector>
      </connectors>
      ...
      <diverts>
         <divert name="multicastToAnycastDivert">
            <routing-name>toAnycast</routing-name>
            <address>dataSubTopic</address>
            <forwarding-address>forwardMessageToCloud</forwarding-address>
            <exclusive>false</exclusive>
         </divert>
      </diverts>
      <bridges>
         <bridge name="my-bridge">
            <queue-name>forwardMessageToCloud</queue-name>
            <forwarding-address>remotePrinectDataForward</forwarding-address>
            <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
            <static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>remote-connector</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
         </bridge>
      </bridges>
      ...
      <addresses>
         ...
         <address name="dataSubTopic">
            <multicast>
               <queue name="dataSubQueue1"/>
               <queue name="dataSubQueue2"/>
            </multicast>
         </address>
         <address name="forwardMessageToCloud">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="forwardMessageToCloud"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
      ...

On the second broker instance I added the following in broker.xml:
      <addresses>
         ...
         <address name="remotePrinectDataForward">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="remotePrinectDataForward"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>

I started both brokers and then used the producer command to send a JMS message to the topic dataSubTopic on the first broker, i.e.:
./artemis producer --destination topic://dataSubTopic --message-count 1

This message was successfully diverted to forwardMessageToCloud and sent across the bridge to remotePrinectDataForward on the second broker.
Based on this it's not clear to me what might be going wrong in your use-case with Spring. Everything appears like it should be working normally as indeed it does in my test.
Regarding the "Unsupported message body type" issue you're seeing on the console when sending the message with the Core client I recommend you send a nullable SimpleString instead, e.g.:
ClientProducer producer = session.createProducer("dataSubTopic");
ClientMessage clientMessage = session.createMessage(true);
clientMessage.setType(Message.TEXT_TYPE);
clientMessage.getBodyBuffer().writeNullableSimpleString(SimpleString.of(message));
producer.send(clientMessage);


In fact, I did not send an empty message, but the writeNullableSimpleString method can solve the "Unsupported message body type" problem. I observed the source code and found that the underlying operation of the buffer is different.
In addition, I rewrote a demo about the above problem. If you have time, you can try it. Here is the address:  https://github.com/1638234804/artemis-problem-demo

I downloaded your Git repo and used mvn spring-boot:run to start node 2 and then node 1. Then I sent a message to node 1 using ./artemis producer --destination topic://dataSubTopic --message-count 1. Then I checked the MessageCount attribute of the MBean for remotePrinectDataForward queue on node 2 and it was 1 which means the message was successfully diverted and bridged on node 1 to node 2. From what I can see there actually is no problem.

Thanks Justin, I think I didn't express myself clearly. In fact, according to your previous answer, I have adjusted the sending code logic of my artemis java Client. Now everything is normal and the web-console can display the message content normally. The problem now is that it cannot send messages with SpringJMS. The SendMessageTest.java in my demo also has examples of successful and failed message sending, but this is not so important. I have given up using SpringJMS to send messages.

How do I run the Spring JMS sender that fails? You didn't provide any instructions or explanation.

An example of SpringJMS sending a message failure is here: https://github.com/1638234804/artemis-problem-demo/blob/dev/artemis-node1/src/test/java/com/artemis/example/SendMessageTest.java

note that the bug with the display of the empty string was reported in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4547 and was solved in 2.32.0

I noticed this problem and I am using 2.19.1artemis
